# File download issue in latest browser versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, mime-types

I am seeing different behavior for my file download in Chrome lower v/s higher versions. So essentially, I dynamically submit a form created inside iframe to get the file download response from server.

```
$(iframe_doc).find('form').submit();
```

Here is one difference I can observe (which is totally strange). So it is a pdf which gets downloaded/displayed as print view.

It works perfectly in older versions and I see the response from server as just this.

```
7867868JHGJGHJGH778
```

However, on the latest Chrome version, I do not see the file getting downloaded and see the response as

```
<!doctype html><html><body style='height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);'><embed name='7867868JHGJGHJGH778' style='position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;'width='100%' height='100%' src='about:blank' type='application/pdf' internalid='7867868JHGJGHJGH778'></body></html>
```

Any reason why the server-side response itself would vary between lower and higher version and why it would not work in higher Chrome version ?

Comment: Well not knowing anything about your server, all I can suggest is to examine the request and response headers. There should be a `Content-Type` header in the response to identify the download as an attachment. I have considerable experience with file download actions and I have not noticed any recent changes with Chrome versions.

Comment: Yes, Content-Type header is present in the response and shows as application/pdf;charset=UTF-8

Comment: But the strange thing is why do the server response itself show as entirely different format between the lower and higher versions !

Comment: Does it also have a `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: I don't know why your server response is different, but then again I don't know anything else about your server either.

Comment: No..it does not have application/pdf;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Would Content-Disposition header make any difference? Not sure what that is used for..

Comment: One other thing is there is for the cookie, in the response header Set-Cookie, I see HttpOnly and Secure flags set...not sure if that would matter in any way ?

Comment: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.pdf"` is what tells the browser that the HTTP response is a download and not something to render to the page.

Comment: Oh k...so probably it did not matter with earlier versions (which is why it works) and we need to set it explicitly with the newer Chrome versions ?

Comment: Yea that's possible but i don't know for sure; I have always included that header for things I intend users to download.

Comment: What if we just add "Content-Disposition: attachment" (and not set filename)

Comment: Just tried with ModHeader (just added attachment)....seems to be working partially....meaning file is atleast showing as downloaded (instead of coming up as print preview)

Comment: The `filename` is optional, but it might be useful to identify to users what the downloadable file contains. The name can include a date and time for example.